# как скрыть текст - имя приложения в окне kde plasma , тема breeze

Tags: linux, kde

вот так выглидит по умолчанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в настройках можно сделать свет окна и текста одинаковыми
но тема breeze - у него меняется и свет иконок вместе с текстом они тоже и 
иконки становятся не видимыми

Comment: Вы бы ещё спросили как сделать окна круглыми. Сделать-то может и можно, но главный вопрос - зачем?

Comment: если можно сделать то как ? если зачем мне этот текст сильно отвлекает  привык без него

Answer (score 0):

если кто хочет скрыть текст 
в настройках в света - делаете окно активного и текст активного окно одинаковыми

breeze - в  дефолной теме это не прокатит пока нашел выход 
устанавливаете невидимый шрифт и этот шрифт ставите настройках в  заголовок окна